# generate predictable unique string based on a generic objects content

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

#### Story

I'm trying to write a **generic method** which combines property names, types and content value to generate a **unique string for** the **value held** by the object passed.

The idea is to generate a **unique SHA3-512 Hash** based on the generated string sequence which **can be used to compare objects** on generic bases **by looking at their content**.

---

#### Example

Let's say we have a class like this ...

```
class MyClass {
    private Int32 Id = 5;
    public String Name = "some string";
    protected DateTime CreateDate = DateTime.Parse("2017-08-21 15:00:07");
}
```

... and the mentioned method to generate the unique string

```
static String GetContentString<T>(T obj) where T : class {
  ...
}
```

**In theory this should work somewhat like this**:

```
var myObj = new MyClass();
var uniqueContentString = GetContentString(myObj);

Console.WriteLine(uniqueContentString);
>>> Id:Int32:5$Name:String:some string$CreateDate:DateTime:2017-08-21 15:00:07
```

---

#### Problem

I'm having difficulties building the `GetContentString` Method. **This is what I have already**:

```
Object obj = ... // given object
Type type = obj.GetType();
IList<PropertyInfo> propertyInfos = type.GetProperties().Where(x => x.CanRead).ToList(); // Marker #2

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (PropertyInfo pi in propertyInfos)
{
    sb.Append(pi.Name);
    sb.Append(":");
    sb.Append(pi.PropertyType.Name);
    sb.Append(":");
    sb.Append(pi.GetValue(obj) ?? "[ISNULL]"); // Marker #1
    sb.Append(":");
}

return sb.ToString();
```

I tried running the method for a few different types of values like `"some string"` or `1234 (Int32)` and ran into a few issues.

Given a string, the method call throws an exception of type `System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException` and the message `Parameter count mismatch` at `#1`. I found out that an optional index can be passed to an overloaded version of `pi.GetValue(..)` which then returns one of the single letters. **But how do you know when to stop?** If you call an index which doesn't exist it throwns an exception of the type `System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException`. **How do you get the value of a string object using reflection?**

Given an integer value, the method call doesn't find any properties at `#2`. Which brings up the question of **how to get the value of an integer object using reflection?**

And also some general questions; **do you guys think this is a good approach to get a unique string? Is reflection the way to go here? Is it even possible to write a generic solution to this problem**?

Comment: Yes, it is possible (solution is quite large but not hard). But a few questions first: why do you need this? is there a problem with GetHashCode() ? Why SHA256?

Comment: It will probably be easier to filter out indexed properties with `.Where(p => p.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0)`, since there really won't be a reliable way for you to provide a value for them.

Comment: SHA3-512 by definition is allowed to create collisions and cannot be “unique”. What are you going to be doing with your hash afterward? [Explain what your goal is, not just what you are doing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @DourHighArch as I said, the goal is to compare objects based on content

Comment: @DourHighArch I am not familiar with the exact specification of SHA3 but since it is used for password hashing I assume that it is unique? Do you have a source?

Comment: If you pass string there - why not just return it back? Why inspect string via reflection? Or I misunderstood something?

Comment: @Evk I figured there must be a solution which works regardless of the type

Comment: Well you have to have special handling for built-in types at least. Inspecting properties of string or int to build a string doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Evk I understand. I'm looking into using some object serializer, that will probably do the trick

Comment: @tobias, all hashes by definition [cannot be unique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function). Think about it, they take variable-length data and return fixed-size output so mathematically they [must allow collisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle). Passwords need not be unique and their hashes need not be unique. What you are proposing cannot possibly work; if you explained what you want and why you think  hashes will do that we may be able to help you.

Comment: @DourHighArch ah I see where you're going with this. This is why I chose a 512bit hashing algorithm because I thought that this must reduce the chance for duplicates. The goal is to serialize an object (including its private fields and properties a.s.o.) to generate a unique hash regarding this object. I want to use this in combination with Entity Framework to easy check if an item already exists in database or not in its current state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without looking at reflection, how about JSON serialization with something that .net framework is able to ?
Reflection isn't something extremely fast and you'll run into issues at the first unhandled exception.

Then, you should do that recursivly if your objects can contains complex properties, wich is not a problem with json serialization !

Comment: That is indeed a very interessting approach and might actually be the solution for this problem. I'm going to try it out

Comment: Just keep in mind that JSON serialization is going to end up using reflection behind the scenes anyway.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I don't mind if reflection is being used as long as it works

Comment: For sure json serialization uses reflection, but there are chances that will be more efficiently done in some nuget packages like newtonsoft or .net framework than hand writted.